# How to get count of unique data with filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I am trying to achieve the count of the filtered data from response.data object. How can I use unique along with the filter

```
{{(gridOptions.data | filter: {ServiceType: 'Basic'}).length}}
```

So I want something like this below

```
{{(gridOptions.data | unique:StudentId |filter: {ServiceType: 'Basic'}).length}}
```

Comment: `unique` is not a core AngularJS filter. To code a custom filter, read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).